# When does a component of a larger project require its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When does a component of a larger project require its own tag? Example:

We have [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity), [dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dash) [launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/launcher) - `dash` and `launcher` are components of Unity, as well as separate packages.

So the question is, do we need/want a master `unity` tag, or have all these other tags?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you can use a tag on a component from a larger project when the project it self can or not incorporate that component.

On the example given `dash` and `launcher` are part of Unity, they *are* Unity. You cannot split them from Unity.

Having a small other component that might work with Unity, even for Unity, but is really not necessary to have to make Unity work would give rights to that component to have it's own tag.

One example of that is [zeitgeist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zeitgeist). It works with Unity and even tough it is necessary to have to be able to use Unity (I think) there is a tag just for it since a lot of configuration can be done for zeitgeist that will not be directly connected to Unity.